# GREP two particular columns

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file with two words on each row, using **GREP** i have to verify two conditions :

1. if first word begins with a specific letter, for example 'A'
2. same for second word but different letter, for example 'B'

i know how to do it verify it only for first word

```
grep '^A' file
```

But how to verify for second word ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^A/ && $2 ~ /^B/' file
```

In case you want to avoid use of regex you can use this awk:

```
awk 'index($1, "A")==1 && index($2, "B")==1' file
```

Here is a `egrep` command for same but prefer `awk`:

```
egrep '^A[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]+B' file
```

Comment: i have to do it using grep

Comment: Why? It's not the right tool for the job. Or is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `egrep` and a regular expression:

```
$ egrep '^A.*\s+B' file
```

`egrep` is also available as `grep -E`:

```
$ grep -E '^A.*\s+B' file
```

The regular expression there is "starts with A, has some characters, then at least one space, then a B".

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
grep '^A[a-zA-Z]* B' file
```

Comment: The first word might have only one letter.